# How do I load an HTML file via PHP and insert data from mySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML file we'll call it dashboard.html.

I have a PHP file called index.php that will load on the webserver by default.

I have a mySQL database called myDb.

From index, how do I load the HTML file dashboard and INSERT data from my SQL database into the appropriate places?

Right now the html file may have a line that reads:  John Doe .  Instead of having a name in that span, I need to replace it with the appropriate PHP to insert the appropriate name from my SQL database.  I actually already know how to echo the data from mySQL to the . What I don't know how to do is load the HTML from the PHP file.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php have a look at this....you should be able to just read in the contents of the html file to a string, and replace content within the string as needed, then do whatever else you need to do with it.

Comment: if you are not beginning & would like to work with template engine you should try with twig,smarty etc.

Comment: @jewelhuq Thank you so much! smarty is amazing, and is going to save me so much time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to it:

1st: Put your html code into your index.php and echo your data on the right place. Simpliest one.

2nd: Use Keys in your html and replace it with the data. For example:

In dashboard.html

```
<input type="text" value="%DATA%" />
```

in your index.php

```
$holeFile = file_get_contents('dashboard.html');
$holeFile = str_replace('%DATA%', $resultSet['column']);
// ...
```

If you choose this way, there are already nice template engines like smarty.

3rd:
Use DOM Objects in PHP and replace it. Mostly the same as 2nd, but in a nicer way. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php)

Comment: wow method 1 is pretty much what I need, and I feel awfully sheepish for not realizing it myself... thank you

Comment: every php code goes to the php interpreter, from any file. It´s important to keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Just follow follow the steps

index.php

```
$name= "xxxxx";
include "dashboard.php";
```

dashboard.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Hello,<b><?php print($name);?></b>
</body>
</html>
```

Change your file name dashboard.html to dashboard.php and put $name variable in index.php file first then include dashboard.php file. Hope it will solve your problem